# kubernetes how to inherite anonntation inheritance from namespace annontation

Tags: kubernetes, annotations, namespaces

Is there a way to inherit annotations to all resources in a namespace?
My naive assumption was that I can annontate the namespace and that resources will get this annontation:

```
kubectl get --export namespaces non-native  -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  annotations:
    foo: bar
  creationTimestamp: null
  name: non-native
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/non-native
spec:
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes
status:
  phase: Active
```

Running

```
kubectl get --export pod -n non-native nginx-6f858d4d45-s2xzl  -o yaml
```

shows no `foo=bar` annotations.

Am I asking for the impossible? Can you achieve this?

#### update:

Although my example shows a Pod, I would like to annotate also other resources, like services, or PVCs etc.

Comment: Hi, maybe podpreset help you? https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/podpreset/

Comment: This is good, but what if the annotation I want is for services? For example https://github.com/kubernetes/cloud-provider-openstack/tree/master/examples/loadbalancers?

Comment: You can write an operator that will work by analogy with PodPreset

Answer (score 1):

I think `podpreset` can help

```
kind: PodPreset
apiVersion: settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1
metadata:
  annotations:
    foo: bar
  namespace: {youNamespace}
```

How enable **PodPreset**:

1. You have enabled the api type `settings.k8s.io/v1alpha1/podpreset`
2. You have enabled the admission controller PodPreset
3. You have defined your pod presets